# Collapsing Tree with Table in HTML starting closed

Tags: html, jquery, tree

I'm using the code in this example http://jsfiddle.net/Vd5BH/5/ and I want to start the tables with the collapsing closed, but I dont have idea on how to do this.
Somebody know?
Link http://jsfiddle.net/Vd5BH/5/
Thanks a lot!

HTML

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0">
        <td><span class="toggle collapse"></span>Item 1</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1">
        <td><span class="toggle"></span>Item 2</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="2" class="collapse level2">
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1">
        <td>Item 4</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse collapsable level0">
        <td><span class="toggle collapse"></span>Item 5</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse collapsable level1">
        <td>Item 6</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

STYLE

```
table td {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.level1 td:first-child {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.level2 td:first-child {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.collapse .toggle {
    background: url("http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/images/collapse.gif");
}
.expand .toggle {
    background: url("http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/images/expand.gif");
}
.toggle {
    height: 9px;
    width: 9px;
    display: inline-block;   
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    $('#mytable').on('click', '.toggle', function () {
        //Gets all <tr>'s  of greater depth
        //below element in the table
        var findChildren = function (tr) {
            var depth = tr.data('depth');
            return tr.nextUntil($('tr').filter(function () {
                return $(this).data('depth') <= depth;
            }));
        };

        var el = $(this);
        var tr = el.closest('tr'); //Get <tr> parent of toggle button
        var children = findChildren(tr);

        //Remove already collapsed nodes from children so that we don't
        //make them visible. 
        //(Confused? Remove this code and close Item 2, close Item 1 
        //then open Item 1 again, then you will understand)
        var subnodes = children.filter('.expand');
        subnodes.each(function () {
            var subnode = $(this);
            var subnodeChildren = findChildren(subnode);
            children = children.not(subnodeChildren);
        });

        //Change icon and hide/show children
        if (tr.hasClass('collapse')) {
            tr.removeClass('collapse').addClass('expand');
            children.hide();
        } else {
            tr.removeClass('expand').addClass('collapse');
            children.show();
        }
        return children;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$('.toggle').click();` as the last item inside `$(document).ready()`.

See the [revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vd5BH/1037/)

```
        //Change icon and hide/show children
        if (tr.hasClass('collapse')) {
            tr.removeClass('collapse').addClass('expand');
            children.hide();
        } else {
            tr.removeClass('expand').addClass('collapse');
            children.show();
        }
        return children;
    });
    $('.toggle').click();
});
```